# How to trace the life cycle of kernel threads by following creation and switching?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, kernel-panic

How to trace the life cycle of kernel threads by following creation and switching ?

kernel_thread() and schedule() are the 2 functions I know that but have no idea how to implement it..